# How to insert DateTime form flutter to PHP MySql using POST

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I'm currently working on flutter with mysql and php. connection to my DB and flutter works fine. and when i insert String it works perfectly. but when i use `DateTime.now()` it throws `Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0`.

my code from flutter is

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  String date = dateFormat.format(DateTime.now());

  var url = 'http://192.168.1.8/konkolata-dashboard/driver.php';
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
    'name' : fullName.text,
    'assigned' : 'false',
    'assignedTo': 'no',
    'created': date,
    'available': 'true'
  });
```

and my PHP side to receiving the post of date looks like

```
$created = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['created']));
```

so how can i insert date from my flutter and receive it from php?

Comment: Show the exact date string being generated by flutter please

Comment: @ADyson its `DateTime.now()`

Comment: Yes I  can see that. But that's not a string. I'm asking you to provide an example of the actual output from that

Comment: @ADyson the date printed is `2022-06-18 15:48:54`

Comment: If we simulate that then there seems to be no problem: https://3v4l.org/r8a9q, at least on the PHP side. The actual error message sounds like a JavaScript error, which is a bit odd. It certainly doesn't come from PHP. Where exactly are you seeing that error message?

Answer (score 1):

Let me just post my solution if it helps anyone. first we need to create a column in our db as DateTime not Date. then in php we initiate it as `$created = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['created']));`, after this in flutter we can assign it as `'created': DateTime.now().toString(),`. this worked for me.

Comment: what if the column in db is a Timestamp? would that work too?